# iPhone + In App purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have a existing application and I want to implement **In App purchase** in this application, so that application is available freely on *App Store* with some locked feature and if user tries to access those locked feature, they will get some message to buy unlock those features by buying the app.

Please tell me steps to implement this or some reference where step by step guidance is available.

Answer (score 10):

Read the [In App Purchase Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Thank you for this brilliant advice. You should know why would anyone ask any question if the programming guides are sufficient for the beginners.

Comment: Still, they should read the docs first and if they are not clear enough for the beginner then they should formulate a specific question to ask. And/or search online for the many good in-app purchase tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

UrbanAirship (http://urbanairship.com/in-app-purchase/) is what you are looking for.